# Does the notation "$\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}\right)$" make sense for $n<5$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, notation, products

In my textbook, in order to solve for the limit of the sequence
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} \tag{1}$$

the book rewrites the sequence 
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}\right)\tag{2}$$

But how can these two expressions be equal? If you plug in numbers $1$ through $4$ into the second equation, it doesn't make sense. For example, for $n=4$, 
$$\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot 4}{4\cdot 4\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot 4}\right) \tag{3}$$ 
makes no sense: $n$ must be $\geq5$ because in the numerator (of the parentheses part) 
$$2\cdot3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n \tag{4}$$
there are two multiplication dots separated by an ellipsis, implying that there is at least one value between $3$ and $n$. Thus, the second equation can only be used for $n$ must be $\geq5$.

My textbook says that 
$$\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}\right) \tag{5}$$ 
can equal $1$ for $n=1$ but technically you have to be able to plug in $1$ for $n$ to say that.

Comment: The conversion you write from $a_n=\frac {n!}{n^n}$ to $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}\right)$ is off by a factor $\frac 1n$.  I don't know what the leading $\frac 1n$ is doing in the second.

Comment: @RossMillikan My bad I mistyped.

Comment: In a now-deleted answer, @fordjones makes the important point that the ellipsis notation represents a *pattern* and shouldn't be taken entirely literally. "$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n$" is a common way to express $n!$, even for $n=1$ through $n=4$, *despite* the notation suggesting that there are terms between "$3$" and "$n$". Without resorting to the somewhat scary-looking sigma notation, the ellipsis notation is simply the most-convenient way to express "the product of the integers from $1$ to $n$" in an arithmetical form. Mathematics, like any language, has its colloquialisms.

Comment: You could click the edit button at the bottom of the post and correct the error.

Comment: @RossMillikan I did

Comment: I think it would have been better just to delete the $\frac 1n$  in the first line under the display equation instead of removing the $1$ from inside the parentheses.  It is clearer then that there are $n$ factors of $n$ in the denominator.  Ellipses are hard because you are relying on the reader to figure out what the terms are.  Here one would have to notice that there should only be $n-1$ factors of $n$ in the denominator.  What you wrote is correct, but not as easy to read as it could be.

Comment: why would you have $x\to2$? And why would a pattern like $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\dots\cdot n$ cause so much perplexion?

Comment: As Ross suggests, it would probably have saved much consternation not to have pulled the factor $1/n$ from the expression. That said, since $n$ is heading for infinity, quibbling over the behavior for small $n$ is a bit of a distraction. *That* said, it's worth noting that an expression such as five $(5)$ *can be* assigned the value of $1$, since it involves "empty products". This is not unlike how, despite the naive definition of $2^n$ as "the product of $n$ copies of $2$", we say $2^0=1$; likewise, how we agree that $0!=1$, despite the definition "the product of integers from $1$ to $n$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that, strictly, what has been written makes no sense. That being said, these kinds of abuses of notation are common throughout mathematics. A more rigorous expression would be 
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n i}{\prod_{i=1}^n n}$$

Comment: For $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}\right)$ I'm still not sure what the domain is. It's a sequence so $n$ must be a positive integer but which positive integers are allowed, strictly speaking?

Comment: Yes, $n$ should be a positive integer. This is another common abuse, some letters tend to mostly be used to denote objects of a certain kind.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{n!}{n^n} ?$$

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n}\right) = \frac{n!}{n^n}$$

if the number of $n$ in the denominator of $$(\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot...\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdot...\cdot n})$$ is $n-1$ which does not seem  so.

Otherwise it is not correct.

Comment: I made a mistake typing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the book they are using that

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2\cdot3\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}{n\cdot n\cdot\,\cdots\,\cdot n}\right)=\frac1n\frac{n!}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{n!}{n^n}$$

and indeed for $n=1$ we have $\frac{n!}{n^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{1^0}=1$.